# YouTubePlayer together with AppCompat v7 library

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-youtube-api, android-appcompat

I have developed an app that uses `YouTube android API` to play a certain video inside the app. At that time I have used as target API 19, and also target API 19. Now I want do change the design of the app switching to `Material Design` using target API 22 and also using `AppCompat-v7 :22+ library`. But the `YouTubeBaseActivity` cant be opened and the application crashes. Below I will post what I have done so far.

EventDetail.java

```
public class EventDetail extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener { .
.
.
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // remove the shadow from action bar
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_TranslucentActionBar_ActionBar_NoOverlay);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_detail);

        // enable back button

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // setting the action bar initially transparent
        mActionBarBackgroundDrawable = new ColorDrawable(
                Color.parseColor("#ec5c59"));
        mActionBarBackgroundDrawable.setAlpha(0);

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(mActionBarBackgroundDrawable);

        // binding the scrollview

...
```

Manifest File

```
<activity
        android:name="com.dev.apk.evente.al.EventDetail"
        android:icon="@drawable/ikona_projekte"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_event_detail"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay" />
```

Layut File:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/video_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="23dp"
    android:paddingRight="23dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/event_background_block" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/video_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"

        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Video"
        android:textColor="@color/VeryDarkGray"
        android:textSize="22sp" >
    </TextView>

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/video_label"
        android:background="@color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Theme.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.TranslucentActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar.Transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/evente_date_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/evente_darken_color</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Theme without ActionBar shadow (inherits main theme) -->

    <style name="Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.NoOverlay" parent="Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

So at the beginning it doesn't open because the method `getActionBar()` return Null, then i changed it to `getSupportActionBar()`  but i doesn't recognized it. Then at the end I changed this line in the following:

```
public class EventDetail extends AppCompatActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
```

and it gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myikub.al/com.dev.apk.evente.al.EventDetail}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #250: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2342)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5406)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #250: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
    at com.dev.apk.evente.al.EventDetail.onCreate(EventDetail.java:112)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5303)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5406)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
    at com.dev.apk.evente.al.EventDetail.onCreate(EventDetail.java:112)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5303)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5406)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ....
```

I am using Android Studio. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to check out more info here : https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the [`YouTubePlayerView`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView), **which requires your `Activity` to extend [`YouTubeBaseActivity`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeBaseActivity)**. Then you changed your activity, so that it now extends `AppCompatActivity`. This breaks `YouTubePlayerView`.

The solution is pretty simple: **use the [`YouTubePlayerFragment`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) class**. This does not pose any requirement on the `Activity`, leaving you with plenty of options for your theming.

Comment: Thanks @dextor, it solved my problem, I have just finished implementing it and it works like before.

Comment: but there is one problem though, when I try to run the application on an  Android Lollipop Device, it gives me the following error : Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START }

Comment: That's because you're using an old version of the SDK. Updating to 1.2.1 fixes this issue.

Comment: @Xhulio can you please answer your question and tell us how to implement YouTubePlayerFragment , also it is a good practice to answer your own question.

Comment: people say `YouTubePlayerFragment` is buggy - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682673/7767664

Answer (score 0):

According to the stack trace the activity has to extend YouTubeBaseActivity when using the YouTube API

If you need to have an actionbar then I think the best route is to change the style to have no actionbar and just use a [toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) in your view.

Answer (score 0):

paste this code inside gradle app

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
```