# How to extend ActionBarActivity and YoutubeBaseActivity?

Tags: android, youtube-api

Is there a way I can extend both of these in a single activity? If yes, please share with me the source code.

Comment: ActionBarActivity ? From AppCompat (suuport-v7) ?

Comment: For eg: I have Activity A and for now it extends ActionBarActivity and since i am using youtube player it also needs to extend YoutubeBaseActivity. So how can i extend both of them in activity A ?

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But ActionBarActivity is deprecated for about a year. You should us AppCompatActivity and with this one, there is 2 solutions for your problem.

Comment: No, you can't. Java doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Comment: @pdegand59 what are the solutions ?

Comment: You can't extends both. Look this example for Play Video and do other stuff http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/

Comment: @bhaskar, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

From [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101825/youtubeplayer-together-with-appcompat-v7-library/30101931#30101931):

To reduce the complexity and simplify the language, Android does not support multiple inheritance as it's based on Java programming language. Hence you can't extend both ActionBarActivity and YoutubeBaseActivity in a Single Activity.

The solution is pretty simple: use the [YouTubePlayerFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) class. This does not pose any requirement on the `Activity`, leaving you with plenty of options for your theming.

Since the version 22.1.0, the class ActionBarActivity is deprecated. You should use [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html).

Answer (score 1):

Note : ActionBarActivity is deprecated, use AppCompatActivity.

Instead of having the Youtube player in the `Activity` (extending `YoutubeBaseActivity`),  make your Activity extends from `AppCompatActivity` and use a [`YoutubePlayerFragment`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) inside the `AppCompatActivity`. You will be able to use all the features of AppCompat with your Youtube video.

If you REALLY want to use `BaseYoutubeActivity`, you have to add an [`AppCompatDelegate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html) in your own `Activity` extending the `BaseYoutubeActivity` and use it in every lifecycle method of your activity. Read the documentation of the delegate and read the original source code of [`AppCompatActivity`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.java) to understand the delegate.

Comment: the hint with AppCompatDelegate was very helpful! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that for now. you can use fragment instead of activity in your Activity that extends AppCompatActivity

Please refer to this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30101931/4321808